# Squid specific incoming port -> outgoing IP on system

Tags: squid

Right now the following works for an incoming connection to a specific port and it uses a specific proxy for the outgoing connection

```
http_port 8000 name=port_8000
acl port_8000_acl myportname port_8000
always_direct deny port_8000_acl
never_direct allow port_8000_acl
cache_peer 54.38.228.38 parent 20006 0 no-query default name=proxy8000
cache_peer_access proxy8000 allow port_8000_acl
cache_peer_access proxy8000 deny all
```

How can I configure Squid so instead of using a proxy for an outgoing connection, I want it to use a specific network interface by providing the IP address of that NIC.

For example if we have 4 NICs on the machine and one of them has the IP of 192.168.2.147, I want to set Squid to use the interface with the IP 192.168.2.147 if we have an incoming connection to port 8000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squid proxy has [`tcp_outgoing_address`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/tcp_outgoing_address/) setting to map requests to different outgoing IP addresses:

`tcp_outgoing_address 192.168.2.147 port_8000_acl`

Comment: Something puzzling. I can get  tcp_outgoing_address to work on a Windows machine, but if I put IP address of a different interface in a Ubuntu machine, then Squid can not connect to using the tcp_outgoing_address. Have you ran into something like that?

Comment: @david My understanding is that for `tcp_outgoing_address` to work, squid had to have been compiled with this setting: `./configure --enable-linux-netfilter`